# 3des decryption in c# from a string returned by event.message.text

Tags: c#, visual-studio, encryption, 3des

How do I properly convert the input text so that it decrypts properly
I get an error saying

Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]'

whats the proper way to parse the first parameter of TransfromFinalBlock of the decryption interface? thanks

```
private static void Bot_OnMessage4(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        ICryptoTransform decrypt = des.CreateDecryptor();
        String[] dd = new String[1];
        dd[1]= utf8.GetString(decrypt.TransformFinalBlock(utf8.GetBytes(**e.Message.Text**, 0, utf8.GetBytes(e.Message.Text).Length)));
        Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, "message to decrypt is  \n" + e.Message.Text );
        Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, "decrypted message is  \n" + dd[1]);
```

Comment: What is the type of `utf8` here? (And why would you convert the string to a byte array twice? I'd definitely do it *once*.) I suspect the problem is *really* just that you've got a `)` in the wrong place... I suspect you want one of your last ones directly after `e.Message.Text` in your first call to `utf8.GetBytes`. If you separated this conversion to a byte array into a separate statement, this would be more obvious :)

Comment: (I'm not going to add an answer as I believe this question should be closed as a typo.)

Comment: @DaisyShipton Nah, there is more going on than just a typo, read my answer to understand why.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: Hadn't spotted that, and I agree with your answer - although I'd say that the *immediate* problem (the error reported) is still a typo. People are unlikely to end up on this question due to the problem that follows on from fixing the typo, unless the question is updated to show the decryption error that's likely to happen.

Comment: @DaisyShipton True, but hey, if I would not answer the encoding / decoding issues then an additional 50% of crypto questions stays unanswered :)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be already trying to fix your issues, correctly blaming your input:

```
utf8.GetBytes(e.Message.Text, 0, utf8.GetBytes(e.Message.Text).Length)
```

The problem is that modern crypto acts on bytes, and returns a ciphertext where each byte can have *any value*. This means that the ciphertext may also contain bytes that do not represent *any character*. In other words, the ciphertext is *not really text*.

So there are two things you can do about it:

1. keep handling the ciphertext as bytes or byte streams;
2. encode the ciphertext to a binary encoding such as base 64 and decode before you decrypt.

Keeping the ciphertext in binary should be preferred, but it is not always possible if the interface with the rest of the system (the `Message` in this case) requires a textual string.

---

Your error doesn't have anything to do about this, but if you follow above advice you don't need `utf8.GetBytes` anymore.

You should use the single argument [`GetBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get rid of the compile error, but your code would still fail during runtime (although it *could* succeed because the right bytes are generated by chance).